# CKEDITOR destroy() throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkFeature' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using the following code to destroy an instance of CKEDITOR (version 4.4.7):

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(iElm[0],options);
ck.on("blur",function() {
    this.destroy(true);
});
```

The code runs fine, the instance is removed from the DOM, but the following error is reported:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkFeature' of  undefined
checkAllowed @ ckeditor.js:178
refresh @ ckeditor.js:177
c @ ckeditor.js:920
j @ ckeditor.js:10
CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire @ ckeditor.js:12
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ ckeditor.js:13
f @ ckeditor.js:215
(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:215
(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:25
```

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: @user1273587 I cannot reproduce in the latest CKEditor. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b947d1e5444b7eb6d39ade715ebd0a26

Answer (score 4):

I found that the following eliminated the error message:

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(iElm[0],options);
   ck.on("blur",function() {
   var editor=ck.name;
   $timeout(function() {
       CKEDITOR.instances[editor].destroy();
   },0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the editor has just the empty div element that we use to hold the editor. So, is it batter to do:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.removeAllListeners();
```